# Why does this program print strings with strange characters? Memory leak despite freeing?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner to C and learning it as part of uni course. One of the practice problems given to us asks us to create a function that returns a user defined string with hyphen ('-') characters added before and after. The user will also define the total number of characters. This function will be called "center" and will be called as follows: center(char userString[], totalLength). So if userString = "cat" and totalLength = 5, then center should return "-cat-".

The center function does its job just fine. It creates a string with hyphens added. However, when trying to print I'm seeing weird characters in the output. I've been told about memory leaks in lectures but I've tried to allocate and free memory.

Center function:

```c
char *center(char s[], int totalLength){
    int dashes = totalLength-strlen(s);

    int i;
    char* ret=malloc(totalLength+1);
    int left = dashes/2;


    for(i=0; i<left; i++){
        ret[i]='-';

    }
    for(i=left;i<strlen(s)+1;i++){
        ret[i]=s[i-left];

    }
    for(i=strlen(s)+left;i<totalLength;i++){
        ret[i]='-';

    }
    ret[totalLength+1]='\0';
    return ret;
}
```

Main function:

```c
int main(void) {
    char s[] = "cat";
    char *ret=malloc(100);
    ret = center(s,5);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    free(ret);
    ret = center(s, 6);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    free(ret);
    ret = center(s, 7);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    free(ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
-cat-
-cat--o
--ca└--
```

Expected output:

```
-cat-
-cat--
--cat--
```

Comment: The `char *ret=malloc(100);
    ret = center(s,5);`  straight up leaks memory. The `malloc(100)` needs to be freed to (or not malloced at all, since it's not used).

Comment: The strange characters do not appear because of memory leaks but because of your incorrect counting of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* ret=malloc(totalLength+1);
...
ret[totalLength+1]='\0';
```

The highest index of an array is one less than the size. A buffer of size `totalLength+1` has indices from `0` to `totalLength`. The misplaced `\0` explains the trailing junk (`o`) on line 2.

```
for(i=left;i<strlen(s)+1;i++)
//                    ^^
for(i=strlen(s)+left;i<totalLength;i++)
//             ^^^^^
```

`+1` and `+left` should be the same to ensure the later loop picks up where the earlier one left off. The mismatch is a sign that one of them is wrong, and it's causing there to be a gap of uninitialized characters, which is why you're seeing garbage (`└`) in the middle of line 3.